# UITableViewDelegate methods not called after Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8 migration

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

After migrating my codebase from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0, I noticed that my `UITableView` footer did not show up.  It turns out that none of my `UITableViewDelegate` methods get called (ex: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`).

Interestingly, the `UITableViewDataSource` methods are being called and the **table is being populated**.  I have set the parent view controller to be the table's `delegate` and `dataSource`.

To illustrate the problem, I have created a [sample Swift 3.0 project](https://github.com/adityatrivedi/miniature-disco) tailored to match my existing codebase as much as possible.  Maybe something changed in Swift 3/Xcode 8 that I am not aware of or I might be missing something really obvious.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I checked your sample project:

You didn't did anything wrong, but referring to `viewForFooterInSection`, it will not get called until you implement `heightForFooterInSection`  method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50 // for example
}
```

**Similar Cases:**

No implementing for `heightForHeaderInSection` ==> No calling for `viewForHeaderInSection` even if it's implemented.

Returning `numberOfRowsInSection` as zero ==> No calling for `cellForRowAt` even if it's implemented.

*Additional Note:* you don't have to add `tableView.dataSource = self` and `tableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`, they have been set in the interface Builder.

Comment: Gotcha!  I am surprised that it worked before without explicitly setting the footer height.  Maybe the new default height is zero.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the height of the footer

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Rroobb!

Comment: Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode8, or latest Swift version, the method signature has been changed. This change might be causing your code to not call delegate method.

Fix it by writing method again using autocomplete.

Old Method -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat? {
    return 50.0
}
```

New Method -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}
```

**heightForHeaderInSection**  has to be used while using **viewForHeaderInSection**.

Hope this helped.