# Set a custom table view footer with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to set a custom footer to my table view. I created the footer on a nib file and created a controlled for it.

```
class LoginTableFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I wrote this code

```
let footerNib = UINib(nibName: "LoginTableFooter", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(footerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "LoginTableFooter")
```

Then I implemented `viewForFooterInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "LoginTableFooter")
    let header = cell as! LoginTableFooter

    return cell
}
```

`viewForFooterInSection` was never called. I also tried to implement `viewForHeaderInSection` but it was also not called. Do you have an idea what is wrong? I have only one section in my table view; is it possible/better to set the footer directly on `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Have you called delegate method of UITableview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewDelegate methods not called after Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8 migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069943/uitableviewdelegate-methods-not-called-after-swift-3-0-and-xcode-8-migration)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implement - delegate & datasource for your tableview and set both -  `heightForFooterInSection` & `viewForFooterInSection`

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

// set view for footer
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return footerView
}

// set height for footer
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Comment: why cant we use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`?

Answer (score 1):

//firstly you need to call the delegate and datasource of table view. i.e:

```
  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self
```

//you need to call this delegate

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      return "your expected footer height"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3
Directly use > viewForFooterInSection

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return footerView
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return footerView
  }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check @borchvm comment. Besides, there are some more replies so you should expose the Cons and Pros of your answer.